# Is using "not have a drop" correct in this context?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage, idioms

Is this idiomatically correct?

> Those feelings kept gnawing at me so I had to turn to alcohol to soothe my nerves even though **I have not had a drop in a while**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context of the idiom is correct, the tense less so.

Based on the first half of your sentence (past continuous), it would be more natural to have past perfect `I hadn't had a drop in a while` rather than present perfect `I haven't had a drop in a while`.

> Those feelings kept gnawing at me, so I had to turn to alcohol to soothe my nerves even though I hadn't had a drop in a while.

Alternatively, the first half of the sentence could be changed to present continuous `These feelings keep gnawing ...` and the rest of the sentence can stay the way it is.

> These feelings keep gnawing at me, so I had to turn to alcohol to soothe my nerves even though I haven't had a drop in a while.

Answer (score 0):

These feelings keep gnawing at me, so I had to turn to alcohol to soothe my nerves even though I haven't had a drop in a while.

To keep the tense of the sentence consistent throughout, wouldn't this be better said as:

These feelings keep gnawing at me, so I have to turn to alcohol to soothe my nerves even though I haven't had a drop in a while.

Comment: Why do you need to keep the tense of the sentence consistent throughout?